# Does Vengeance have any comic history?

Tags: dc, batman, the-batman

Spoiler Alert for those not having seen the film yet.

In the 2022 film *The Batman*, Bruce Wayne is not yet known as Batman but introduces himself as *Vengeance*:

The letters are addressed to *To the Batman*:

[image: Letter from the Riddler to Vengeance]

Important note for me: *To **the** Batman* and not *To Batman*, i.e. the Riddler implicates the costume and is not calling him Batman. Does the form of Vengeance appear in comics or is this a new interpretation in the film?

Comment: https://youtu.be/4xbbpH-20ak?t=22

Comment: http://www.pauldwaite.me.uk/images/hello.png

Comment: In the Batman comics Vengeance is Bane's supervillain (clone) daughter.

Comment: I an pretty sure he is stating his purpose, not giving his name.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line "I am vengeance, I am the night, I am Batman!" most famously first appeared in the TV show Batman: The Animated Series. This line most recently appeared in the live action movie The Batman (2022), after Batman beats up a thug and being asked who he was, he replied with the savage line "I am Vengeance!".

The Director of the movie The Batman (2022) earlier stated that he had taken inspiration from the comics "Year One" (1987), "The Long Halloween" (1996-97) and "Ego" (2000).

But it was in "Batman: Earth One"(2012-21) when Batman first identified himself as "vengeance" in a comic book:

[image: man: "You? Who are you?" Batman: "Vengeance"]

Note: I will like to point out that in the movie Batman doesn't introduce himself as vengeance rather he shows that he embodies vengeance as a symbol of sorts.

My answer shows the comic book history of Batman identifying himself as vengeance.

Answer (score 0):

In the comics, [Vengeance](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Vengeance_(Prime_Earth)) is the daughter/clone of Bane. It gets very confusing.
Her name is a reference to the first appearance of Bane in Batman: Vengeance of Bane #1.

I do not believe Batman has ever officially taken the name "vengeance" in any of the main series in any significant capacity yet. Even in the movie, "vengeance" doesn't seem like an actual name.